# Nesting a TEXT statement in an IF statement

Tags: calculated-column

I need a calculated column to return the `mmm` of a Date Field. Except, if the Date Field is empty, I would like the calculated column to also be blank.

The original formula for the month is `=TEXT([Date],"mmm")`. This returns 'Dec' if the Date field is empty.

I tried `=IF(ISBLANK([Date]),"", &TEXT[Date], "mmm")` but am getting an error.

Is this sort of thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date]), "", TEXT([Date], "mmm"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You get December for an empty date becuase SharePoint starts counting dates at 31 december 1899

Your formula is almost correct, just some typos:

This should work: (I added some spaces for clarity)

```
=IF(  ISBLANK([Date])  ,  ""  ,   TEXT([Date],"mmm")   )
```